# symfony2 - datetime picker - combine form types into one

Tags: forms, symfony, datepicker, datetimepicker

I am looking to create a re-usable datetime picker in symfony2.  The idea is it will consist of 3 separate input parameters.  I will update the question with complete info so other people can use my findings.

{text input} {select hour} {select time}

The question is how do I create a custom re-usable form that combines 3 inputs into one.

I have attached a screenshot to give an idea of what im trying to achive

[image]

the symfony docs
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-a-template-for-the-field

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can simply use the [jquery.datetime picker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) to show a datetime picker or just one of them(date or time).

i recently made on one of my website.

```
$builder->add('dateheure', 'datetime', array('date_widget' => "single_text", 'time_widget' => "single_text"));
```

and call jquery, datetime css and js on your page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.datetimepicker.css"/ >
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

and then active datetimepicker on your fields:

```
$(function(){
    $("#form_dateheure input").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("readonly","readonly");
    });
    $('#form_dateheure_date').datetimepicker({
        format: "Y-m-d",
        timepicker: false,
        datepicker: true,
    });
    $('#form_dateheure_time').datetimepicker({
        format: "H:i",
        timepicker: true,
        datepicker: false,
        step:5
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As a example you can see to [DateTime](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html) field. Check the [source code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/DateTimeType.php).

Broadly speaking, first create the [Custom Form Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html), which when you can add to your forms. As example

```
class DateTimeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('date', 'text');
        $builder->add('hour', 'choice', array(...));
        $builder->add('minute', 'choice', array(...));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'form';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'date_time';
    }
}
```

Second add [Data Transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) to it, which will transform your html data from 3 field into one `DateTime` object.

Comment: thanks for the feedback I think im heading in the right direction.  How do I implement the type into the form.  I have tried it and get Expected argument of type "object, array or empty", "string".

Comment: What is your entity field `custquote_pickup` type?